# Fetch Core Data relationship template

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

I'm a little bit confused try to fetch relation data from coredata in swift using templates.

I'd like to focus in my two entities Conversation and Messages (one-to-many relationship)

Here is my schema.
[image]

I want to write a template, which allow me to fetch all messages on specified conversationId.

Is it possible to make such request in Data Model editor?